# ASP.NET MVC doesn't cast Model object in aspx page  to appropriate having sended Model to this page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

**EDITED**

I have a problem. ASP.NET MVC doesn't cast Model to appropriate View Model in *.aspx page. For example:
I passed MyViewModel(with propery MyProperty) to page (return View(MyViewModel) in Action in Controler), but then at runtime I get an error like this.

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'MyProperty' and no extension method 'MyProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Where object in my context is Model object in aspx page.

We are using this workround  `<% var model= Model as MyViewModel; %>`. and using model where we should use Model.
 How to make Model working?

***EDITED***

This is top directives

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/BaseViewMaster.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Organization.Core.ViewModels.Models.MyViewModel>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Resources" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Organization.Core.ViewModels.Models" %>
```

Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<Organization.Core.ViewModels.Models.BaseViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Organization.Core.ViewModels.Models" %>
```

Comment: Same problem here. Have you ever found a real solution?

Comment: Yes, Read my comment for Artur Mustafin.

Comment: That is just a workaround :( I did the same at the end...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be trying to cast a model in your view. Use the appropriate strongly-typed view, instead:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>" %>
```

Then, just refer to `Model` in your view.

If you need to convert from an EF domain model to your view model, do it in the controller method, either manually or using something like Automapper.

Comment: We use this Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>. It dont work in this project.

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more details. Post the View code (at least, the top section with all the directives in it). What do you mean, it doesn't work? Do you get an ASP.NET compilation error at runtime? Have you @include'd the namespace for `MyViewModel` in your view or in the <pages> section of web.config?

Comment: I have added directives in question. Yes, I got ASP.NET error at runtime. ----Have you @include'd the namespace for MyViewModel in your view or in the <pages> section of web.config?; Answer: No. And It seams does not help too.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem after converting a MVC2 application to MVC4. The problem in my case was in the Web.config file *within* the Views folder. I created a new MVC4 project and copied the default Views/Web.config over top of  my existing Views/Web.config and that fixed the problem.

I *believe* the issue was in the `<pages>` node where some of the version numbers were not at 4. I'd guess the pageParserFilterType because of the nature of the problem, but I am not sure about that. At the time of this writing with my specific version, this is what the pages node looks like now, and it works for me:

```
<pages
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deeply, terribly wrong, you shouldn't cast **View** to **ViewModel**, because it will always return false, null, or throws an exception.

In related sample, for example in any typical M-V-VM related projects, classes related to Model, View and ViewModel, are in covariance...

So, M, V, VM are loosely coupled, so there is no common root classes to be translated into.

- class **AbstractViewModel** -> ... -> Your view's **ViewModels** (UI bindings, behaviors, data bindings)
- class **AbstractView** -> ... -> Your **Views** (pages, screens, etc.);
- class **AbstractModel** -> ... -> Your **Models** (algorithms, business layer, etc.)

These hierarchies is not likely to be in one tree except for the object base class due this will break loose coupling and deprecate the idea of separation presentation logic (presenter, view-model) from model and visual desighn (views, controls)

In the most DI frameworks, dependencies injects as a public read-only properties, so try to look (depends on M-V-P, M-V-VM, M-V-C implementation) , for example ((1)dot(2) means read-only property (2) in a class named (1), some of them could be also internal, so not accessible:

- **ViewModel.View**
- **ViewModel.Model**
- **View.ViewModel**
- **Model.ViewModel**

The actual names of the properties may differ, but the logic aren't.

In your case, you most likely missed that property:

```
<% var model= Model.ViewModel as MyViewModel; %>.
```

or

```
<% var model= (Model as MyModel).MyViewModel; %>.
```

or simply

```
<% var model= MyModel.MyViewModel; %>. (if you are the  M-V-VM frameworks developer like me)
```

Comment: With all respect to you. You should read again my question. You should read what Steve Morgan said and my comments. The problem is not in naming my Model or ViewModel. The problem in that I get runtime error when I write something like that in my aspx file(in View) <%= Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Deck) %> OR <%= Html.Hidden(Model.Deck) %>. ASP.NET MVC does not see Deck propery in Model object. The workaround is to use this line of code <% var model= Model as MyViewModel; %> and then write <%= Html.HiddenFor(m=>model.Deck) %> OR <%= Html.Hidden(model.Deck)%>